# Multiple choice story

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a multiple choice story, also known as a text adventure.

Below is a example of what little I have finished so far.

```
  import time
while True: 
    print ("You awaken with a splitting headache and are very disoriented.")
    time.sleep (2)
    print (" ")
    print ("Slowly standing up you begin to relise you are in a dark corridor with no view of the end on either side")
    time.sleep (2)
    print (" ")
    d1a = input ("Do you want to: A) Go Left. B) Go Right. [left/right]? : ")
    if d1a in ['left', 'right']:
        break
time.sleep (2)
print (" ")
if d1a == "left":
    print ("You slowly edge your way left, going into the dark unknown...") 
elif d1a == "right": 
    print ("You slowly edge your way right, going into the dark unknown...")
```

What I need help with is after a person answers the questions and gets "You slowly edge your way right/left, going into the dark unknown..."  I need to make it so depending on how they answer more text appears and the opportunity to add more questions, depending on which answer they choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep writing under the relevant print statements, if you keep the indentation. If I understand it right depending on whether the user goes left or right entirely different sets of questions will show up? If similar questions will show up for awhile but the story will diverge based on the collection of answers then I suggest you keep track of the answers with variables and then tell appropriate story branch using if statements. This should work reasonably well if you keep the story short.

For a more complicated approach you could put different parts (think chapters or rooms) of the story in functions responsible for printing out the relevant text, querying the user's responses and then reporting these responses back to the main program loop which then in turn is in charge of calling up the next function in the story.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. I would suggest you change the input string from `"Do you want to: A) Go Left. B) Go Right. [left/right]? : "` to `"Do you want to Go Left or Right. [left/right]? : "`

The reason why is because the user might enter A or B, and your program will not like that as a response.

You can define a function that will take in a string, and in that function you have a if statements statement that will print the appropriate message. You can also have many functions that you call after each input the user makes.

instead of breaking out of the loop, you can call a function.

Example.

```
import time

def goLeft():
    print ("You slowly edge your way left, going into the dark unknown...") 
    ##call another function that will continue the game.

def goRight():
    print ("You slowly edge your way right, going into the dark unknown...")
    ##call another function that will continue the game.

while True: 
    print ("You awaken with a splitting headache and are very disoriented.")
    time.sleep (2)
    print (" ")
    print ("Slowly standing up you begin to relise you are in a dark corridor with no view of the end on either side")
    time.sleep (2)
    print (" ")
    d1a = input ("Do you want to go Left or go Right. [left/right]? : ")

    if d1a == 'left':
        goLeft()
    elif d1a == 'right':
        goRight()
    else:
        print("You died!")
        break

time.sleep (2)
```

The function can then lead the person to another function, and so on. You can even take an integer parameter in which you print random messages based on the number of turn the user is taking.
I really like how you have started tho. Keep going.

Comment: Would you be able to implement that into the work I have already?  I appreciate your answer and understand it, to a degree, but I am not sure where to implement it.  I am self-teaching so I truly know the very basics.

Comment: Implement what? Try running this program and see how it works. I want you to give this a try because you are not going to learn if I do the work for you. I have defined 2 functions which you can use to build on top of. If you get stuck you can always leave a comment here and I can answer to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

i guess u want to use some method to label the players previous game path?

i would talk u some ways:

1、use variables to label the previous answers.

```
answer1 = "left"
answer2 = "right"

if answer1 == xxx and answer2 == yyy:
   pass
```

but it becomes complicated if the question number is big.

2、just into some function base on what u choose last.

```
def answer2OnLeft():
    pass

def answer2OnRight():
    pass

if answer2 == "left":
    answer2OnLeft()
else:
    answer2OnRight()
```

This way u can manage the relation of the choice and result easy,but the fall is u can only link to the last question and its answer.(Maybe u can try to add a parameter context in the function to represent the previous answers)

3.In more complicated situation, u can use the status machine. Click the link below to get more information.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine